# MIPS interrupt won't jump to the interrupt handler

Tags: mips, interrupt, interrupt-handling

These values are loaded into the registers

```
lui  $t0, 0xffff             # Loads receiver control
li   $t3, 0x00000002         # Loads the interrupt enable bit
```

This function enables MMIO input interrupts.  It will loop until the game is over
and wait until a key is pressed.  This will trigger the interrupt handler.

```
main:
beq  $s7, 1000, checkOver    # Every 1000 loops checks to see if the game is over
sw   $t3, ($t0)              # Enables interrupts
addi $s7, $s7, 1             # Adds one to the loop iterator
j    main                    # Loops in main until the game is over
```

However when I press a key I get this error instead

Error in C:\Users**** line 41: Runtime exception at 0x00400038: External Interrupt

I get this error instead of the code going to my interrupt handler which I have written in .ktext.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, and I'll post it here just in case anyone else has the same problem.  I assumed that .ktext has a defined address in memory, but it turns out when you define .ktext you need to hard code the location.  Where I had

```
.ktext
```

I should have put

```
.ktext 0x80000180
```

Then the code properly jumps to the interrupt handler.  Took me awhile to find.

Comment: This is for the `mars` simulator [and the address can be reconfigured]. Here's the documentation: http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/MarsExceptions.html